# Browsing the content of a folder embedded in an uberjar in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to list the content of a folder located in the /src/main/resource/ folder of my SpringBoot application. The folder contains regular files. The code works perfectly fine in the IDE (STS) but not once the application is packaged.

Here is the code:

```
    Resource xCatRawResource = resourceLoader.getResource(xCatRawResourcePath);

    try(
            InputStream in = xCatRawResource.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
    ) 
    {               
            byte[] bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(in);
            String data = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            // data is an empty String when app is packaged

    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to parse XCAT names", ioe);
    }
```

I tried different strategies (using ResourceUtils etc...) but without success.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Reflections library - read more about it [here](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).:

The POM for the latest version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

An example of how to use it:

Assume you have a directory called `jsonfiles` in your `/src/main/resource/` directory.

The following code will print out the contents of the `jsonfiles` directory:

```
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.ResourcesScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Set;

...

Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME.HERE"))
        .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner()));
Set<String> resources = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile("jsonfiles.*"));
resources.forEach((resource) -> {
    System.out.println(resource);
});
```

The output will be something like this:

```
jsonfiles/json_file_one.json
jsonfiles/json_file_two.json
```

I have tested this in a fat/uber JAR.

Disclaimer: I don't use Spring - so if that is somehow causing your issue, then my solution may not work. But I would expect it to.

(A small point: I notice that, in your question, your code defines a buffered reader `br` which you don't use - you use the input stream `in`.)

Comment: Thank you, that's nice! I'll accomodate for Spring... yes I skipped a part of the code to make the example easier to read (`br`)